# Is this use of "prone" in Hiero's Journey an error, a crass commentary, or something else?

Tags: terminology, hieros-journey

I was rereading Sterling Lanier's 1973 novel *[Hiero's Journey](https://archive.org/details/hierosjourney00ster)* this week, because I was trying to determine whether I remembered correctly that it contained a giant centipede.  (So far, there hasn't been one, but there was a giant lamprey.)  However, I was struck by the following passage about the protagonist's telling off of his lover before leaving on the titular journey:

> He had confessed before leaving the Republic, to Abbot Demero in fact.  And telling Leolane d'Ondote that she was going to be neither his first, second or indeed any other wife, and further that her talents were exclusively **prone** was not a mortal sin, even if more than a trifle rude.  And that was the heaviest guilt currently on his mind.

Its sense seems to be that Hiero told Leolane d'Ondote that he had only been interested in her physically, and that he had no interest in her apart from sex.  However, the appearance of *prone* appears wrong here.  *Supine*, meaning "lying on one's back" would be a more normal way to express the sentiment that a woman's only talents were sexual.  So this seems like either a) an error, b) a sly comment about the sexual positions preferred by Abbey priests like Hiero, or c) a reference to something else that I am not getting.

The word *prone* only appears one other time in the novel, and although it is not perfectly clear, that usage is more suggestive of falling on the belly (the correct meaning of the word).  Of the three relevant uses in Lanier's other novels, *The Unforsaken Hiero* and *Menace Under Marswood*, two more naturally refer to people lying on their bellies, and one definitely refers to a dead enemy lying facedown.  So Lanier clearly knew the meaning of the word.  That does not rule out a temporary slip on the author's (or editor's) part, but it does point to the possibility that Lanier might actually have meant something else.  If so, is there some other interpretation that I am missing?

Comment: it may have an erotic meaning

Comment: From what I can tell, the implication is that if she's *supine* she has the opportunity to talk to him during sex (which he doesn't want, or value). Her 'talent' is that she can be used as a mere sexual object.

Comment: He uses the term "prone" extensively in his various novels. He clearly knows what the word means. *"He fell prone—face ground into the sand—behind it as the tiny Osmium wrecker bomb went into its nuclear cycle,*", etc.

Comment: I agree with the above comments. In terms of the character's expectations being dashed - going from high-hopes to her true function of being demeaned.

Comment: I recall no giant centipede in "Hiero's Journey"; perhaps in the 1983 sequel, "The Unforsaken Hiero"?